# Is there a Drupal API function for retrieving text filter settings?

Tags: input-formats

I've created a custom text filter, building on the [filter_example.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/filter_example%21filter_example.module/7.x-1.x).  The filter lets the admin enter a setting for the filter (just like the "foo" filter in the example lets the admin set the string to substitute for "foo" everywhere in the text).

However, I want to use one of the filter setting in a hook somewhere else in my code base - something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_something().
 */
function mymodule_something(&$vars) {
  $vars['foo'] = _filter_variable_get('myfiltermodule', 'foo');
}
```

AFAIK, the function `_filter_variable_get()` does not exist. I am able to create it myself.  The following works as one would expect.

```
function _filter_variable_get($module, $filtername) {
  $setting = db_query('SELECT settings FROM {filter}
    WHERE module = :module', array(':module' => $module))->fetchField();
  $settings = unserialize($setting);
  if (isset($settings[$filtername])) {
    return $settings[$filtername];
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

However, getting text filter sttings seems such a common thing to want.  Am I supposed to roll my own, or is there a Drupal API call for this?